# How to modify a redux variable state from react component with a button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am working on react-redux project for quite sometime now. In redux I have an id variable with initial state of **0**. I want this value to be changed on button click. For this to happen, I have two buttons, *button1* and *button2*. when I click on **button1** I wanted to change the **id** state to **1** and **2** when I click on **button2**.

Here is my code.

**idReducer.js**

```
const processReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ID":
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export { processReducer };
```

**action.js**

```
export const id = () => {
  return {
    type: "ID",
  };
};
```

reducerAll.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { tokenReducer } from "./tokenReducer";
import { userDataReducer } from "./userReducer";
import { userStatusReducer } from "./userStatusReducer";
import { assetRiskReducer } from "./assetRiskReducer";
import { cpeReducer } from "./cpeReducer";
import { processReducer } from "./processReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  token: tokenReducer,
  user: userDataReducer,
  user_status: userStatusReducer,
  assetRisk: assetRiskReducer,
  id: processReducer,//MY ID REDUCER
});
```

ChangeState.js components with two buttons to change the state of **id**

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { id } from "./../../../auth/store/actions/index";
const ChangeState = () => {
  const id = useSelector((state) => state.id); //initial state of id=0
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={}>button1</button>
      <button onClick={}>button2</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChangeState;
```

**Problem:** When button1 clicked, I want to change the state of **id** to **1** and **2** when **button2** clicked.

Thanks.

Comment: The `processReducer` doesn't do anything other than return the current state value. If you want to update state, the reducer function is where it's done. Your `id` action creator also hasn't any payload. What are you wanting to do with your state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your reducer to actualy do something with paylad:

```
const processReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ID":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export { processReducer };
```

make your action to pass id as payload (i would consider to use something better as name of action instead of `id`):

```
export const id = (id) => {
  return {
    type: "ID",
    payload: id,
  };
};
```

and then call your action onclick using dispatch with this ID

```
const ChangeState = () => {
  const id = useSelector((state) => state.id); //initial state of id=0
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>dispatch(id(1))}>button1</button>
      <button onClick={()=>dispatch(id(1))}>button2</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: God Bless You Man! Thanks!